# What team compositions are viable?

Tags: league-of-legends

So basically I want to know all the metas for league of legends? Some that I know would be AOE comp and Poke comp that's pretty much all I know. Are there any others and what counters what?

edit Ahh you know what as pointed out by Kleme Quixote the question is more about comps and not the meta.

Comment: @Scootaloo This question has a weird title. If you read the description, the original goal was to learn more about the different team comps. I would recommend that we change the title of this one.

Comment: @Shaun What do you think we should change it to?

Comment: @Scootaloo Something like "What are the types of team comp strategies that are viable?" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Meta" has been interpreted into so many different ways throughout the community.

Today's "Meta" is more so an overall composition on how all teams are set.

It consists of the Bruiser Top, Bruiser Jungle (Keep in mind, almost all champions can jungle now), AP Caster Mid, AD Carry Bot, 0 CS Support Bot.

Some counters would be anti-mages mid, such as Kassidan or Sivir, and anyone with strong harass bot, to prevent the enemy carry from farming.

This counters the current meta, as in my interpretation.

For AOE Comps, A quick silver sash and cleanse work wonders against escaping heavy CC.
For Poke Comps, I suggest high sustain, High durability.

Answer (score 5):

The current Meta for North American Servers as I understand it goes like this:

- Top Lane is manned by a champion that has enough sustain to hold the lane on his own without much help from the jungler. This can be a bruiser, but can also be many other heroes, with the only important criteria being filled is the hero is solid enough of a pick that he can at least hold his own ground and farm enough to be of assistance when laning phase ends.
  @PunDefeated also made a good point, that sometimes the enemy team will swap their duo bot lane with their top laner. The purpose of this is to pressure the top lane with a 2v1 matchup to quickly bring down the enemy tower and give the aggressive team an early gold advantage. It's important to know this may happen, so optimally, your top lane hero should be able to hold his own against a 2v1 matchup, at least long enough for the friendly jungler to get his butt in gear and give top lane a hand. (I personally almost never see this happen, but it DOES happen from time to time)
- Mid Lane is manned by a carry of some sort, usually AP type or Assasin type. These Champions serve to burst down key members of the enemy team in teamfights once laning ends. They often have extremely high, if not sustained burst damage, and also usually but not always have a Crowd Control ability of some sort.
- Jungle is usually manned by a bruiser of some sort (but not always), with a heavy focus on mobility and ganking potential. It's also extremely popular at this time that the jungler has the ability to counter-jungle, that is, not only clear the friendly jungle, but safely clear the enemy jungle as well so as to stunt the growth of the opposing jungler.
- Bot lane is manned always by a RANGED AD Carry of some sort, and a Support for said AD Carry.

  - The ADC should be farming as much minions as possible, while staying in lane as much as possible, and killing the enemy bot laners also, as much as possible, with the focus being to farm minions and **NOT DIE**. The idea is to have a smooth early and mid game so to bring to the late-game High sustained DPS.
  - The Support should be not farming CS, doing most (but not all) of the warding for the team, as well as doing everything possible to make the life of the friendly ADC easier. A skilled player once told me its the Supports job to carry the ADC so the ADC can carry the team. Supports generally (but not always) have some combination of these abilities: they can heal, they can shield, they can speed up allies, they can slow down enemies, they have some sort of damage steroid for allies, they have some sort of damage nerf for enemies, and they have some form of CC. It is also necessary that a support's abilities work good enough to produce the desired effect all game, with minimal items to help, as without CS supports tend to make very little money compared to other champions on the team.

Any META that involves a 'poke' or an 'aoe' strategy in NA still follows the guidelines stated above, only it narrows down champion choices to involve champions that carry to the game a strong presence of the stated mechanics.

- Poke is the ability to repeatedly damage enemy champions from a safe distance, with the purpose of wearing them down so they can be killed by a final 'all in' burst of damage.
- AOE is the concept of abilities that damage multiple champions simultaneously.

In closing, the Meta tends to be somewhat different for each region. If your interested in the other floating Metas I cannot help you, but enough research into the pro-league games of their respective region should give you some insight into how others are playing.

Comment: It may be important to note the prevalence of lane swapping in professional play, where one team (generally purple, I think) sends their "bot lane" to top lane, in order to take the enemies top turret quickly and give their own team a favorable gold advantage.  This has had an interesting effect of lowering the variety of top lanes played at a high level, because they need to be able to deal with the pressure of a 2v1 and being forced to farm under turret.

Comment: @Ender The purpose of a block quote, though, is to actually *quote* something. If those are related you could do so with a separate heading or I believe markdown may support sub-bullets.

Comment: @StrixVaria ok, ill give that a try. :)

Answer (score -1):

Pushing comp beats poke comp, by experience and proven by many many teams.

Comment: How does that explain what possible metas exist out there? You said "X beats Y", while the question demands "There are A, B, C, D, E, F, G..."

Answer (score -1):

Try the Tank comp, pick 5 heavy tanks on ranked get into lategame and win 
(cho, Singed, Rammus, Mundo, Galio, Malph, Volibear...)

We got till 1500Elo in season 1 with that ^^

EDIT: counter would be an awesome early game comp or tank busters (kog maw^^)

Comment: Lots of Atma's on your team and Deathfire Grasp on the opponents? ;)

Comment: Doesn't work as well now in Season of the Ruined King.